# How to resize width of a Jquery dialog after initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the width of a JQuery dialog after it has been initialized. Here is my initialization:

```
$(function() {
$("#dialogContainer").dialog({
title: 'Some title',
resizable: false,
bgiframe: true,
overlay: { opacity: 0.3, background: "white" },
position: [200, 200],
autoOpen: false,
height: 150,
width: 'auto'
modal: true,
buttons: {
  'ok': function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
  }
}
```

});

});

And this is what I am doing to change the width of it in some other function:

```
$("#dialogBox").dialog('option','width',700);
```

But this doesn't work. The width of the dialog is the width of the paragraph that's first displayed in it. Was I suppose to do anything else?

Here is the html for the dialog:

```
<div id = 'dialogContainer'>
  <p id = 'message'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: NONE of these has your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=resize+jquery+dialog

Comment: Nope, I've been through these before

Comment: Is it just that you are using "#dialogBox" instead of "#dialogContainer" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that you are using ui.resizable.js and ui.resizable.css

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us where to find these files. I don't have them as a part of jQuery 1.12

Comment: @DAB: These are part of jquery-ui

Comment: If it's already part of jQuery UI, them wouldn't it already be included? How did this solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

**Initialize the dialog with the width option specified:**
The width of the dialog is in pixels.

```
$( "#dialogBox" ).dialog({ width: 500 });
```

**Get or set the width option, after initialization:**

```
// getter
var width = $( "#dialogBox" ).dialog( "option", "width" );

// setter
$( "#dialogBox" ).dialog( "option", "width", 500 );
```

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: worked for me, tks

Answer (score 3):

HERE IS SHORT SOLUTION, But remember it is only for predefined dialog.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({minHeight: 300,minWidth:500});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#dialogID").data("width.dialog", 160);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#dialogID").css("width", 160);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  The point is to resize **after** open it:

```
$('#dialogContainer').
    dialog('open').
    dialog('option', 'width',   'auto').
    dialog('option', 'height',  'auto');
```

jQuery version in my case is 1.11:

```
> Query.fn.jquery
> "1.11.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dialogweb").dialog({width:'90%'});
```

Comment: The question already has a valid answer, and it wasn't related to the incorrect use of the width argument for jQuery UI Dialog.